# Populate values from one table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to populate an empty table(t) from another table(t2) based on a flag field being set. He is my attempt below and the table data.

```
UPDATE 2014PriceSheetIssues AS t
JOIN TransSalesAvebyType2013Combined AS t2 
SET t.`Tran_Type`=t2.`Tran_Type` WHERE t.`rflag`='1';
```

When I run the script, I receive (0) zero records affected.??

```
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| Tran_Type | RetailAvePrice | WholesaleAvePrice | Rflag | Wflag |
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| 125C      |            992 |               650 |     1 | NULL  |
| 2004R     |           1500 | NULL              |     1 | NULL  |
| 4EAT      |           1480 |              1999 |     1 |     1 |
+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: When you say "trying to populate," it sounds like you're trying to do an `INSERT`. **What** isn't working and show your desired results.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it seems like he is doing an `UPDATE`

Comment: @Arian I don't know how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: Yes, @FreshPrinceOfSO was correct, inserting into the table.   This worked: INSERT INTO 2014PriceSheetIssues (tran_type,RetailAvePrice)
 (SELECT tran_type,RetailAvePrice FROM TransSalesAvebyType2013Combined WHERE `Rflag`='1');

Comment: @user3099756 good for you for figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just do the following

```
INSERT INTO 2014PriceSheetIssues 
   ( `fldX`, `fldY` )
VALUES (
    SELECT `fldX`, `fldY` 
    FROM TransSalesAvebyType2013Combined 
    WHERE 2014PriceSheetIssues.`rflag`='1'
)
```

The select query gets the values and the insert puts it in the (empty) other table.

Comment: I'm looking into the TransSalesAvebyType2013Combined table where the 'rflag' is set and grabbing the Retail fields to populate the empty 2014PriceSheetIssue table.

Comment: All you have to do it alter the SELECT query to select the right values you want to INSERT and then make sure the fields match.